# Notation for certain filters on real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, notation, filters

Is there any "standard" notation for the filter of neighborhood of positive infinity (on real numbers)?

I mean the filter with the base $\{\mathopen]x;+\infty\mathclose[ : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

I also ask the similar question for the filter of neighborhood of negative infinity.

Comment: What do you mean by "filter"? Presumably not "filter" as in "ultrafilter"?

Comment: @PatrickStevens Why not? I mean the usual definition of filter and usual definition of its special case, ultrafilter.

Comment: You're looking for a name for "filter on the interval $(x, \infty)$"? One such filter being "all subsets of $(x, \infty)$ which contain $2|x|$"? I'd be very surprised if there were a term for such objects.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I am looking for a name (or rather notation) of the filter with the base $\{ (x,+\infty) \mid x\in\mathbb{R} \}$.

Comment: Oh, I understand now - I think it's much clearer what you mean when it's expressed in set notation like that. (I thought you intended $x$ to be some fixed real, in which case the question makes no sense.)